# Wrap CNTK Applications

Tags: c#, python, neural-network, cntk

I've gone through the documentation of Microsoft's OpenSource AI Library CNTK and did understand how to create and train neural networks. I've also understood, how to "save" the trained results into an output directory.

However, I don't see a way to load the results into the neural network and even more complicated: how do I wrap my trained neural network into an application, so I can actually use it in production instead of just using it for academic research.

I want to integrate my neural network into my Python or C# application.
How do I wrap it into such, and how do I create an interface towards its input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have added a Wrapper for C# and C++ a short time ago.

C#
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Source/Extensibility/CSEvalClient

C++
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Source/Extensibility/EvalWrapper

Some guys are already working on a python wrapper also. However, but wrapper it into c++ you can already integrate the c++ solution as a python wrapper library.
Confer: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/

Comment: I finally succeeded using the C# wrapper to get results consistent with the test command results using CNTK.exe, see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/160). If you have any struggle with the wrapper let me know I probably had the same problem before...

Comment: For C# wrapper is just running CNTK as console application. Do you know if there are any plans for pure C# wrapper as Nuget Package?

Comment: c# link is dead as of 12/13/2016

Comment: The link for C# is now https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/Evaluation/CSEvalClient